Python vectors2d class optimizing vector addition
I have been trying to optimize my vector2d class, in particular i want to reduce the time it take to do the vector_addition function.
import copy
import math

class vector2d:
    
    #class variables
    
    #builders
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Empty vector
        """
        self.components : dict[str:float] = {}
        self.components["x"] = 0
        self.components["y"] = 0
    
    def from_x_y(self, x : float = 0, y : float = 0):
        """
        Vector declared using x and y components
        """
        self.components["x"] = x
        self.components["y"] = y
        return self
    
    def from_module_angle(self, module : float = 0 , angle : float = 0):
        """
        Vector declared using module and angle
        """
        self.components["x"] = module * math.cos(angle)
        self.components["y"] = module * math.sin(angle)
        return self
    
    #copy
    def __copy__(self, memodict={}):
        return vector2d().from_x_y(self.get_x(), self.get_y())
    
    def __deepcopy__(self, memodict={}):
        return vector2d().from_x_y(self.get_x(), self.get_y())
    #getters
    #components
    def get_component(self, key : str) -> float:
        """
        Returns a component
        """
        return self.components[key]
    
    def get_components(self,*keys : str) -> tuple[float]:
        """
        Returns the value of the components of the vector\n
        Uses the name of each component as the parameter
        Slow
        """
        components_list : list[float] = []
        for key in keys:
            components_list.append(self.components[key])
        return tuple(components_list)
    
    def get_x(self) -> float:
        """
        return the x component
        """
        return self.components["x"]

    def get_y(self) -> float:
        """
        return the y component
        """
        return self.components["y"]
    
    #module
    def get_module(self) -> float:
        """
        Returns the module of the vector, works for any n dimension vector
        """
        module = math.sqrt(sum(map(lambda i: i * i, self.components.values())))
        return module
    
    #get angle
    def get_angle_2d(self) -> float:
        """
        Returns the angle of a 2d vector
        """
        #atan2 is already robust against division by zero
        angle = math.atan2(self.components["y"],self.components["x"])
        return angle
    
    #setters
    #components
    def set_components(self,*keys_values : tuple[str | float]):
        """
        Sets the components of the vector
        ## parameters
        ### keys_values : tuple 
        first value is the key of a component\n
        second value is the value of the component
        """
        
        for x,y in keys_values:
            if x not in self.components.keys():
                raise ValueError(f"{x} is not a component in the vector")
            if not isinstance(y,float) and not isinstance(y,int):
                raise ValueError(f"{y} should be type float or int not {type(y)}")
            self.components[x] = y

    #module and angle
    def set_module_angle(self, module : float = 0 , angle : float = 0):
        """
        Set module and angle of a vector
        """
        self.components["x"] = module * math.cos(angle)
        self.components["y"] = module * math.sin(angle)
        return self
    
    #set to zero
    def clear_vector(self):
        """ 
        sets all the components to zero
        """
        self.components["x"] = 0
        self.components["y"] = 0
    
    #vectors operations
    def vector_addition(self, vector : 'vector2d'):
        """
        Returns the sum of the two vectors
        """
        add_vector : vector2d = vector2d()
        add_vector.components["x"] = self.components["x"] + vector.components["x"]
        add_vector.components["y"] = self.components["y"] + vector.components["y"]
        return add_vector
    
    def scalar_multiplication(self, multiplier : float):
        """
        Returns the vector multiplied by a scalar value
        """
        multiply_vector : vector2d = vector2d()
        multiply_vector.components["x"] = self.components["x"] * multiplier
        multiply_vector.components["y"] = self.components["y"] * multiplier
        return multiply_vector


This is the code i am using for testing the speed
import cProfile

from simpy_starlinetor.physics_starlinetor.vectors import *

vector_1 : vector2d = vector2d().from_x_y(10,10)

vector_2 : vector2d = vector2d().from_x_y(20,20)


def test(vector_1, vector_2):
    for i in range(100000):
        vector_1.vector_addition(vector_2)


cProfile.run("test(vector_1, vector_2)")

And this is the output
200004 function calls in 0.135 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.135    0.135 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.034    0.034    0.135    0.135 test.py:10(test)
   100000    0.075    0.000    0.101    0.000 vectors.py:123(vector_addition)
   100000    0.026    0.000    0.026    0.000 vectors.py:9(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.135    0.135 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

What i think would probably help a lot is to ditch the dictionary to store x and y but that would require rewriting a lot of code, so if there is some other way it would be best. If there is no better way i will stick to rewriting everything.
I already removed lot of stuff and simplified the code to directly use the vocabulary instead of iterating with the keys, i also removed copies where i could.
This is the before code that is around twice as slow
    def vector_addition(self, vector : 'vector2d'):
        """
        Returns the sum of the two vectors
        """
        add_vector : vector2d = copy.deepcopy(self)
        for key in add_vector.components.keys():
            add_vector.components[key] += vector.get_components(key)[0]
        return add_vector

I would like to make it at least 10x faster but ideally the faster the better

Why not just use Python's complex type? For example your set_module_angle is pretty much what cmath.rect does but without the ridiculous overhead that your implementation entails

What if i need higher dimensions support ?
When i wrote this class i intended it as a generic n dimension vector, that is why the old code iterated between all the keys.

You should keep in mind that CPython (standard implementation) is an interpreter so any basic things are slow (unless they are vectorized). PyPy can help (but not for the inefficient dicts). Moreover, generic code is generally slow too (except in native languages likes C++/Rust). Thus, a generic pure-Python code running in CPython is one of the worst possible thing performance wise.

If you need an arbitrary length vector, just use numpy. Or is this an exercise to learn techniques?

The main issue is the overhead introduced by the use of dictionaries. Since the dictionary-based structure is slowing down operations, switching to a simpler attribute-based implementation for x and y can significantly improve performance.
import math

class Vector2D:
    # Builders
    def __init__(self, x: float = 0.0, y: float = 0.0):
        """
        Vector declared using x and y components.
        Default is an empty vector (0, 0).
        """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def from_module_angle(cls, module: float = 0.0, angle: float = 0.0):
        """
        Vector declared using module and angle.
        """
        x = module * math.cos(angle)
        y = module * math.sin(angle)
        return cls(x, y)

    # Getters
    def get_x(self) -> float:
        return self.x

    def get_y(self) -> float:
        return self.y

    def get_module(self) -> float:
        """
        Returns the module (magnitude) of the vector.
        """
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def get_angle(self) -> float:
        """
        Returns the angle of a 2D vector.
        """
        return math.atan2(self.y, self.x)

    # Setters
    def set_x(self, x: float):
        self.x = x

    def set_y(self, y: float):
        self.y = y

    def set_module_angle(self, module: float, angle: float):
        """
        Set module and angle of the vector.
        """
        self.x = module * math.cos(angle)
        self.y = module * math.sin(angle)

    def clear(self):
        """
        Sets both components to zero.
        """
        self.x = 0.0
        self.y = 0.0

    # Vector operations
    def vector_addition(self, other: 'Vector2D') -> 'Vector2D':
        """
        Returns the sum of the two vectors.
        """
        return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def scalar_multiplication(self, multiplier: float) -> 'Vector2D':
        """
        Returns the vector multiplied by a scalar value.
        """
        return Vector2D(self.x * multiplier, self.y * multiplier)

test:
import cProfile

# Testing optimized Vector2D class
vector_1 = Vector2D(10, 10)
vector_2 = Vector2D(20, 20)

def test_optimized(vector_1, vector_2):
    for _ in range(100000):
        vector_1.vector_addition(vector_2)

cProfile.run("test_optimized(vector_1, vector_2)")

This achieves 3x faster performance with minimal changes. Also If further speed is needed, using NumPy or in-place operations will provide additional benefits.
